# Мне нужно чтобы после того, как видео заканчивалось, открывалась другая Activity

Tags: java, android

```
public void BBpast(View view) throws InterruptedException {
        if (sc <=0){

        }else {
            sc = sc - 1;
        }
        if (sc == 1) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            videoPlayer =  (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
            Uri myVideoUri= Uri.parse( "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video);
            videoPlayer.setVideoURI(myVideoUri);
            videoPlayer.start();


        } else if (sc == 2) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            videoPlayer =  (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
            Uri myVideoUri= Uri.parse( "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video);
            videoPlayer.setVideoURI(myVideoUri);
            videoPlayer.start();
            while (videoPlayer.isPlaying()){
                if (videoPlayer.isPlaying()){

                }else{
                    setContentView(R.layout.kartinkanew);
                }
            }

        } else if (sc == 0) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            videoPlayer.start();

            setContentView(R.layout.kartinkastaraynonachalo);
        }
    }
```

Это функция, которая запускает видео после нажатия на кнопку, нужно чтобы после перехода на Activity с видео после 10 секунд открывалась другая Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Если надо открыть другой экран через некоторое время - используйте [таймер](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/timer.php).

Чтобы сделать переключение между экранами приложения - используйте [Intent](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/activity.php).